# Why is the closing parenthesis of an ECHO command not redirected into text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to `echo` a line of text to a file but the closing parenthesis never echos to the file when executing the .bat script. This DOES work if I run the command straight from the command line.

```
echo DECLARE @MyFileName varchar(1000) >> "C:\File.sql"
```

I have attempted escaping this with 1, 2, 3, and even 4 carets `^` without luck.

I attempted creating a `set %endpar%=)` to pass it in as a variable `echo DECLARE @MyFileName varchar(1000%endpar% >> "C:\File.sql"`, but that also doesn't work. The output is always `DECLARE @MyFileName varchar(1000` with no closing round bracket.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Full code:

```
set backupsql=C:\CF\Backup RCM DB.sql
if not exist "%BACKUPSQL%" (
    echo DECLARE @MyFileName varchar(1000^) >> "%BACKUPSQL%"
    echo SELECT @MyFileName = (SELECT 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.RCM\MSSQL\Backup\DB-RCMDBBackup' + convert(varchar(500),GetDate(),112) + '.bak')>> "%BACKUPSQL%"
    echo BACKUP DATABASE [RCMDB] TO  DISK = @MyFileName WITH checksum, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'RCMDB-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10>> "%BACKUPSQL%"
    echo GO>> "%BACKUPSQL%"
)
```

Comment: What about escaping all of the other nested closing parentheses too?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't echo `DECLARE @MyFileName varchar (1000` to the output file, it throws the error `GetDate() was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: @SomethingDark You are 100% correct, I was editing one script and clicking a copy of the script somewhere else! So, I don't see that error even if I put a pause in. When I add the escape character, nothing happens with the script any more... I get the `DECLARE @MyFileName varchar (1000` when there is no escape character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my comment, you'd do it like this:

```sh
Set "backupsql=C:\CF\Backup RCM DB.sql"
If Not Exist "%BACKUPSQL%" (
    (
        Echo DECLARE @MyFileName varchar(1000^)
        Echo SELECT @MyFileName = (SELECT '%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.RCM\MSSQL\Backup\DB-RCMDBBackup' + convert(varchar(500^),GetDate(^),112^) + '.bak'^)
        Echo BACKUP DATABASE [RCMDB] TO  DISK = @MyFileName WITH checksum, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'RCMDB-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
        Echo GO
    ) 1>"%BACKUPSQL%"
)
```